# Facebook Reviews

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

Can my customers post reviews on my page https://www.facebook.com/pg/RedSeaDivingSafari/reviews/?ref=page_internal from my website through Facebook api?
so i get reviews
$scope.getReviewsInGroup = function (pageId, userAccessToken) {

```
    ezfb.api('/' + pageId + '', 'get',
            {
                fields: 'access_token',
                access_token: userAccessToken

            }, function (response) {

        $scope.accessTokenPage = response['access_token'];

        ezfb.api('/' + pageId + '/ratings', 'get',
                {access_token: $scope.accessTokenPage}, function (response) {


            console.log(response);


        });

    });

};
```

According to the instructions, you can only read reviews https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings. Is there any possibility to embed them on our page, through our website, before our client logs in via Facebook, after he writes the text of the review on the website, and the review should be added to our business facebook page. This is vital for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible.

It would probably lead to massive amounts of spam / fake reviews, if those could be published via any API.